# Does RGBA work with css inline for newsletter

Tags: compatibility, opacity, background-color, newsletter, rgba

I'm creating a newsletter and there are some colors which I would like to have some transparency. So, is it possible to use RGBA as a background-color?

Is it comptaible with all email readers?

Example:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
    <tr> 
     <td> 
      <hr height="1px" width="320px" style="border:none;background-color: rgba(235, 173, 21, 0.3);"></hr> 
     </td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't use RGBA consistently in emails. One of the many quirks of email design is the way it recognizes color declarations both in CSS and in the old-style HTML tags.

These work:

- bgcolor=“#770000”
- style=“color: #770000;”
- style=“background-color: #770000;”

Don’t use these:

- style=“color: red;”
- style=“color: rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);”
- style=“color: #700;”

All shorthand, color names, 3-digit HEX codes and RGBA values do not work consistently across all email clients.

You’ll notice I made use of the bgcolor tag. You should use this old-style method to set the background on all your  and  elements - just like other old-style declarations such as width and border.

A quick note about Gmail (not sure if this has been addressed since):

Gmail has a quirk where it ignores #000000 (black) and #FFFFFF (white) in hyperlinks. Use #000001 and #FFFFF9 instead as a work around.

Comment: short and clear John, thank you! In my design before doing this question I used the rgba property and for now it been accepted by most email readers, excepto of course windows outlook 2007. They just ignore it. Is there a way to create a fallback? So if the RGBA does not work, a simple "border-color:#ebad15" would work. Is this possible with inline CSS?

Comment: you could try declaring the rgba afterwards, in theory it would overrule, but i've never tried it. Alternatively you could make a css rule in the head to target outlook

Comment: what do you mean with afterwards? Something like this: Style="border:#324245;border-color: rgba(255,277,13,0.5);" what that be a kind of inline CSS fallback?

Comment: This is starting to merge into the other post... if you want, you can try putting it in HTML first via the border="1" border-color="#324252" , then put your rgba in a style tag afterwards. In theory if the CSS doesn't work it should fallback to the HTML declaration